# Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'id', table 'XXX'; column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails

Tags: sql

I am getting an insert error:

> Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'id', table 'db.dbo.table';
>   column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails

.

I have checked the data and the column I am inserting into 'id' does not have any nulls. 
Any suggestions?

Comment: Please, provide SQL flavor, table schema (definition) and insert statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error

> column does not allow nulls

is happening because you are trying to *insert* data which has `NULL` for the column `id`, for at least one record which you are trying to insert.  It has nothing to do with the state of the column *before* you attempted the insert.  Check the source of your insertion data and remove/replace the `NULL` values, or alter the `id` column to accept `NULL`.

Comment: I checked the data none of the records have NULLs for the columns I matched it with... i cannot alter the id column

Comment: What version of SQL and/or language are you using?  There must a `NULL` somewhere in the data being inserted.

Comment: I found some Null but when I do `column_id_to_insert = NULL` then nothing comes up

Comment: You can't compare `NULL` using the `=` operator, you need to use `IS NULL`, so use `column_id_to_insert IS NULL` instead.

Comment: @PeterSun: you can't check with a select if the row you are going to insert contains null values. The select only sees _existing_ rows, but the row you are about to insert does not yet exists (and your error is clearly about `INSERT`)

Comment: If the Id is primary key then we cannot follow your step. It won't allow nulls. What would be solution to this?

Comment: @RohanRao It is a somewhat moot point to suggest using `NULL` as a permitted primary key value.  Since all PK values must be unique (identifiers), what would we get by allowing a single record to have a `NULL` PK?  (Now `NULL` foreign keys are another story; they are certainly allowed).

Answer (score 1):

When looking at your SQL table design, scroll through "Column Properties" to "Identity Specification".  In that drop-down, change "(Is Identity)" to Yes.  This setting tells the table to auto-increment the ID field.

Answer (score 0):

Null is not a particular value, but rather, an indication that you don't know the value for this field. It means, "VALUE UNKNOWN". If the field is not NULLable (i.e., if "UNKNOWN" is not permissible), then the INSERT will not be allowed. This is particularly true for an ID column, which might be INDEXed — perhaps even the PRIMARY KEY of the table. Some databases do not allow NULL in INDEXes (particularly primary indexes) at all.